# Failed to Start Service for Snap Application rocketchat-server

Tags: server

i am new to using snap and rocketchat-server.

I installed it using snap and initially it worked fine. however, I wanted to install auto ssl. that would not work so i changed /etc/hosts file from
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 host.fqdn

to 
127.0.0.1 localhost
 host.fqdn

Installed Auto SSL
Cannot get rocketchat to work in browser or apps...i get connection refused (even if i disable firewall on my VPS providers network)

I get the following from logs...

Dec 05 10:50:16 host.fqdn systemd[1]: snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 05 10:50:16 host.fqdn systemd[1]: snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 05 10:50:17 host.fqdn systemd[1]: snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Dec 05 10:50:17 host.fqdn systemd[1]: snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 05 10:50:17 host.fqdn systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.
Dec 05 10:50:17 host.fqdn systemd[1]: snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 05 10:50:17 host.fqdn systemd[1]: snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 05 10:50:17 host.fqdn systemd[1]: Failed to start Service for snap application rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.

Mongodb is running no problems.
i am running on latest ubuntu.

I am not sure how to fix this? Or problem solve it for that matter?

EDIT....
ok i have found that if i shut down rocketchat-caddy, i can then restart rocketchat-server.

However, irrespective of whether or not caddy is now running, as soon as i browser either http or https rocketchat-server fails immediately.

any ideas on why?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to stay away from snaps. They simply load too slowly and make things too complicated.

I would follow the manual installation steps from here:
https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/ubuntu/#manual-install